# How to loop through multiple excel sheets, perform manipulation, and concatenate data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a few thousand excel sheets, which I want loop through, extract a chunk of data and concatenate into one file.

All the excel files are in ("desktop/excel")

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook



os.chdir("desktop/excel")


for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
wb = load_workbook(f)
wb.active = 0
ws = wb.active
data = [[]]
buf = pd.DataFrame()
found = 0
pair=0
out=0
max_row = ws.max_row+1   # Max number of rows in the workbook
max_col = ws.max_column+1 # Max number of columns in the workbook
```

### Extracting required data

```
  for x in range(23,26):
    for y in range(1,max_col):
        if(ws.cell(row=x,column=y).value):
            if not pair:

               buf.append(ws.cell(row=x,column=y).value)
               pair=1
            else:

                buf.append(ws.cell(row=x,column=y).value)
                data.append(buf)
                pair=0
                buf=()

    if pair:
        buf.append("n/a") # completing the value pair by 
                           #adding "NA" next to the field 
        data.append(buf)
        pair=0
        buf=()




print("---------------------------------------")
for x in range(len(data)):
print(data[x])
```

I expect to get a concatenated list of of these individual files, but I keep getting the following error:

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid.

I am very new to Python, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: What kind of file do you want to store the resulting data in? If it's XLSX then I do not see what you're trying to do with Pandas.